# Error 404 (not found) in ajax call with file inside FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I'm trying to invoke a PHP script to upload a file via Ajax.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
console.log(file);

var xhr = $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/it/file/upload/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: fd,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,

  success: function(result, message, xhr)
  {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

For the moment, the PHP script simply displays the received file data

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_FILES['file']);
die();
```

The "file" object passed to ajax data is the following

```
File {errors: 0, name: "wedding.jpg", lastModified: 1500572565619, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 20 2017 19:42:45 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale), webkitRelativePath: ""…}
```

But when ajax call is invoked, in the inspect window I get the following error

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST https://www.mywebsite.com/it/file/upload/ 404 (Not Found)
```

It sounds very strange, since when I directly browse the script path, it doesn't give any 404 response.
If I comment the "contentType" parameter the error disappears, but the received response from PHP script is `null`. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the content type to what is expected. As you mentioned in your post, the `php` file has

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

So, try changing it

```
 contentType: false,
```

to

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: This avoids the Error 404 (not found), but unfortunately I still receive a null response from the server (just like the $_FILE['file'] variable hasn't been initialized).

Comment: Now, that could be due to your logic written in your file. That you need to debug, if required then create a new post with your investigation

Comment: Totally agree with you. Thanks for the help.