# Error in AjaX file upload: uploaded file is null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I'm trying to upload a file via Ajax.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);

var xhr = $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/it/file/upload/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: fd,
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  processData: false,

  success: function(result, message, xhr)
  {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

For the moment, the upload PHP script simply displays file data

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_FILES['file']);
die();
```

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257368/error-404-not-found-in-ajax-call-with-file-inside-formdata/45257488#45257488), I am forced to use `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"` because `contentType:false` causes a `404 (Not Found)` error. 
Unfortunately, this solution avoids the 404 error, but the displayed file data is `null`.

Comment: You have set flag that says 'fd' is file.

Comment: what is `file` in `fd.append('file', file);` , is it an uploaded file from a html page or a file directly assigned to script? .While asking questions, please give the minimum details for easier issue reproduction.

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK: `file` is a variable containing file data (file is uploaded from an HTML page): `File {errors: 0, name: "wedding.jpg", lastModified: 1500572565619, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 20 2017 19:42:45 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale), webkitRelativePath: ""…}`

Comment: @LucasH. what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I made a site which contains portfolio feature and I cropped image using Carrierwave functions.

Comment: ok, let me try...

Comment: `contentType` should be set to `false`, right now jQuery thinks you're sending a JSON string, not a formData object containing  a file that looks like it's an image, and that ends up as `null`. If your server returns 404 you fix that, you don't change the contentType to something that isn't valid

Comment: @adeneo: you are right, setting `contentType` to `false` was my first choise. I've tried to contact hosting managers, but they complained that it was a bug in my code and give up looking for the issue. The curious fact is that if I manually browse the upload path, it works correctly (say, the response code is 200 instead of 404).

Comment: That is strange, the URL shouldn't have anything to do with the contentType? I still think you have to remove the contentType, otherwise jQuery will try to validate the data being sent as JSON, and an image isn't JSON, and will be `null` instead, so that's likely the issue

Comment: @adeneo Just some further details: setting `contentType:false` and passing  a generic key-value `fd.append('dirname', 'somedir')` to ajax call, works correctly (if I print `$_POST['dirname']` correctly outputs `somedir`). When the passed value is a file object, the Error 404 code is returned from server. It seems that the file object is not accepted from server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this. It is working for me.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'), //url_to_php_script
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
           //do necessary cleanups on success 
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //do necessary cleanups on failue
        }
    });
```

You will be able to get uploaded image in PHP using `$_FILES`

Comment: Unfortunately the `contentType: false` statement gives me a `404 (not found)` response from the server. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok the way you're doing it, however...

If you set `contentType` to false, than you will force jquery not to set the content type for you. If it is not set, it will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'.

That means you are sending your data using an url encoded string.
You can't easily send a file in an url encoded string.

Most likely the method on the server side is set up to read the form parameters from the url. Therefor if you set `contentType' to false, the server won't recognise the url, resulting in a 404.

Try setting up the server method to accept post data, remove the url parameters and read the posted form from the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` variables.

If you can't figure it out, update the question with the servers' method so we can see how the method is set up.